# boolean modifier removing the exact opposite of what i want it to?

Tags: modifiers

i’m trying to animate the marvel title card and i want to engrave the marvel text through the metallic box but when i apply the boolean modifier to the box it removes the box and not the text (i have converted the text to a mesh)

before:
[image: this is before I do the boolean]

after:
[image: this is after]

sorry if this is stupid I only started blender a few days ago and couldn't find an answer to this anywhere

Comment: Boolean modifier can be a bit finnicky sometimes, if the booleans cutting the wrong way try giving the text the boolean modifier and setting "back" as the object instead. Also try changing the solver to fast instead of exact, as exact is a bit broken from my experience.

Comment: @NascentSpace i changed it to fast and switched the objects and the back cut into the text as a normal boolean should. so i switched the objects again and changed it to fast and it cut out the M, E, and part of the V but the rest of the letters stayed without cutting. i looked on the underside of the back and saw that the R had almost cut all the way through but hadn’t made it all the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select the box, go to modifiers -> add boolean modifier.
As object you select your text mesh.
Choose intersection.
Apply.
Delete your text.
Ready.
If this was too fast, checkout my tutorial video:
https://youtu.be/Zshq7pk8Psg

Comment: Thank you so much, Chris! That worked perfectly and I really appreciate you taking the time to make a whole tutorial for it. Subscribed!!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, but I discovered that it was caused by the normals of the model being inverted (the outside was on the inside and the inside was on the outside). To view the orientation of the faces, you can go to the drop-down menu to the left of the material views next to the two overlapping circles.

The blue colour should be on the outside of the mesh. If this is not the case, you can fix it by selecting the red parts in edit mode, then going to the mesh drop-down menu, selecting "normals," and clicking "flip."