# How to get this type of engraved metal with shaders

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

The effect I want to achieve is pretty close to the image. I already have the shader for the base metal but I can't get the engraved effect for the text. I wanted to make it using shaders but any other sugestions are also welcomed. Thanks

This is the effect I want to get

[image]

This is my shader
[image: This is my shader for the base metal]

This is how my shader looks like
[image]

Comment: engraved text: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213982/boolean-modifier-removing-the-exact-opposite-of-what-i-want-it-to

Comment: Please make it clear whether you wan't to fix your metal effect or have engraved text. For engraved text, you will have to create an image (You can use software like adobe illustrator or photoshop etc.) and in it have the text you wan't to engrave on your object. (Make sure to have your font right.) Once that is done, add that image as an image texture in the shader editor and with a color ramp node connect it to a bump node which will be connected to the principled BSDF. After that, do some uv editing and adjust your texture, and your engraved text will be ready to go.

Comment: Yes I do want to have engraved text on it. But I wanted it to have a different texture on the text (like in the first image) and I can't get that